# Find line number or an element in a txt file

Tags: python, find, line

I want to find line number of some element in a .txt file.

I created an example .txt file to show here and the code I wrote is working only with the first row of it.
However, with a real file it doesn't find anything, but compiles without a problem.

```py
#create an example file
example=np.array([[1.0, 2.1e-06, 3.3], [5.0, 6.3, 7.8e-03]]) 

filename='/home/Desktop/example.txt'

np.savetxt(filename, example,  header ='exmpl')

#find the line number of a lookup value in the txt file

lookup = '2.1e-06'  


with open(filename) as fp:
    for num, line in enumerate(fp):
      if lookup in line:
            print(num)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two strings and when you save np array to text file the precision before `e` changes thatswhy even if value are same string doesn't match.

I have come up with this solution. I am not master at numpy and python but i know some of this tricks. Feel free to suggest more elegant or obvious ways to do this.

```
import numpy as np
#create an example file
example=np.array([[1.0, 2.1e-06, 3.3], [5.0, 6.3, 7.8e-03]]) 


filename='/home/Desktop/example.txt'

np.savetxt(filename, example,  header ='exmpl')

#find the line number of a lookup value in the txt file

lookup = 5.0e-00


with open(filename) as fp:
    for num, line in enumerate(fp):
        for i in line.split():
            #print(i)
            try:
                if float(i) == lookup:
                    print(num)
            except ValueError as e:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because numpy by default saves the value with trailing decimals:

```
0 # example

1 1.000000000000000000e+00 2.099999999999999799e-06 3.299999999999999822e+00

2 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.299999999999999822e+00 7.799999999999999642e-03
```

So try looking up against that float explicitly:

```py
lookup = 2.1e-06

with open(filename) as fh:
    # skip header
    _ = next(fh)

    for i, line in enumerate(fh, start=1):
        numbers = list(map(float, line.split()))
        if lookup in numbers:
            break

print(i)
```

Or, using the `filter` operator:

```py
lookup = 2.1e-06

with open(filename) as fh:
    # skip header
    _ = next(fh)

    for i, line in enumerate(fh, start=1):
        check = next(filter(lookup.__eq__, map(float, line.split())), None)

        # check will be None if the iterator is exhausted (no match)
        # otherwise, it will stop at the first True
        if check is not None:
            print(check)
            break
```